# Display all active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongrel

in my test mongrel server output for a page, 8 queries are listed but many more DB are counted:

Query1
Query2
...
Query8
Rendered Partial1
Rendered Partial2
..
Rendered Partial40
Completed in 4754ms (View: 308, DB: 2246) | 200 OK

how do I show all the queries that are running?

Also, is there documentation for what the View; count represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but are you asking what the number after DB means? If so, it's the number of records returned.

Some sample output from my Mongrel server:

```
Processing AlbumsController#show to xml (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-22 06:44:38) [GET]
  Parameters: {"format"=>"xml", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"albums"}
  Album Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `albums` WHERE (`albums`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1
  Album Columns (0.8ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `albums`
  Artist Columns (2.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `artists`
  Artist Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE (`artists`.`id` = 1) 
  Track Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE (`tracks`.album_id = 1) 
  Track Columns (1.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `tracks`
Completed in 48ms (View: 1, DB: 22) | 200 OK [http://localhost/albums/1.xml]
```

You see only 3 queries here, but 22 records are returned. If you want to see all of the records that are being shown, display them in your templates. Or, you could easily display them in XML in your controller.

```
def index
  @records = Record.find(:all)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @records }
  end
end
```

Long story short, you are seeing all of the queries.